# Is there a definitive family tree?

Tags: online-resources, dark

On [the official website](https://dark.netflix.io) for *Dark*, there's [an interactive family tree](https://dark.netflix.io/en/family-tree), which shows the family tree based on which episodes you have seen.

I read somewhere there is a family tree that shows the full tree, taking into account the ending of the series. However, I can't find it on that site.

Is there definitive family tree for the situation at the end of the final episode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When writing this question, I looked for the Reddit thread where I read about the existence of a definitive family tree. I found another thread that not only confirmed it, but also disclosed how to reach it.*

---

<sub>*Instructions hidden in their entirety, since they contain spoilers for the ending of the series which I could not easily separate from the rest.*</sub>

> Go to [the family tree](https://dark.netflix.io/en/family-tree), having selected episode 8 of season 3, and select Jonas or alt Martha. After scrolling through their entire timeline, you reach the point where the timeline would loop back to the start for any other character. If you scroll past that point it goes back to the family tree instead. We see the family tree dissolve in golden particles, being replaced with the family tree of the origin world.
>  If you select any of the characters to view their timeline, then go back to the family tree, a full family tree with all three worlds is shown.